# Typing this.$store within a Typescript Vue2 component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, store

Starting from a [minimal Vue2+Vuex typescript app created with `@vue/cli`](https://github.com/cefn/vuex-store-typing/commit/1b2dab24fe4b88ea989bdef0200a0560c651635c). I want to ensure references to `this.$store.state` within a component are of the correct type declared by the Vuex store and its modules.

How can I achieve this? Without intervention, all references to `this.$store` resolve to `Store<any>`.

In [this commit](https://github.com/cefn/vuex-store-typing/commit/389c5edad6f5cbb5dd84ec794fac5130df9a49ca) I changed the default `src/store/index.ts` created by `@vue/cli` to introduce a `message` property in the store...

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

interface RootState {
  message: string;
}

const state: RootState = {
  message: "olleH",
};

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
  modules: {},
});
```

In [this commit](https://github.com/cefn/vuex-store-typing/commit/e5ce11b8e94793eab51c9fb7312744c2c5b56f8a) I updated `shims-vue.d.ts` to read as follows following [guidance online](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#typing-store-property-in-vue-component) to add global typed references to the Vue VM (I suspect the approach only applies to Vue3 though, given the URL of this documentation is next.vue...)...

```js
import type { HelloStore } from "./store";

declare module "*.vue" {
  import Vue from "vue";
  export default Vue;
}

declare module "@vue/runtime-core" {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $store: HelloStore;
  }
}
```

Attempting to get autocompletion support within VSCode for `this.$store.state` still doesn't give me a `message` property.

I can't find any guidance for how to achieve this for Vue2 anywhere.

What is the pattern I should use so that `this.$store` gets the proper typing within my Vue2 components using Vuex3. It seems crazy that you can't get properly typed values with the latest stable releases of these tools. What have I missed?

The repro at https://github.com/cefn/vuex-store-typing is my reference case for anyone wanting to experiment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module name you're using in your type augmentation is for [Vue 3 only](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#augmenting-types-for-globalproperties) (the code is slightly [different in Vue 2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins)), but support for type augmentation of the `$store` instance property was only [added in Vuex 4](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/994). It's not possible in Vuex 3.

However, you could actually use the exported `store` instance (already [typed as `HelloStore`](https://github.com/cefn/vuex-store-typing/blob/e5ce11b/src/store/index.ts#L21)) instead of `this.$store`, as they're the same instance:

```js
import store from '@/store' // store type is HelloStore

export default {
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$store === store) // => true
  }
}
```

Comment: I arrived at a workaround which is better than nothing at https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/994#issuecomment-1025004935, but it means that I can't use `this.$store` and have to keep 'mapping' the contents of the store into every component, when I would prefer to just use the store state directly and not add boilerplate for every access to every value that every component makes. I think the technique of importing `store` has the same issue, right? Assuming I want to reference store contents within templates, I have to keep remapping every usage into locally named properties within the VM.

Comment: Indeed the remapping would be inconvenient if it's frequently needed. In that situation, I would create a new Vue global property that aliases `$store` with the desired type. That would enable type inference in the template as well, as long as you use the new global property instead of `$store`.